# Enum issues, or is it my understanding?

Tags: c++

I'm adding a enum type to the very few bits of C++ I've learnt so far, but having trouble to set it...Am i missing some fundamentals?

```
class Rectangle
{
public:
    Rectangle();
    ~Rectangle();
    enum rectangle_directions_t {R_LEFT = 0, R_DOWN = 1, R_RIGHT= 2, R_UP = 3, R_NONE = 4};
    void setRect(rectangle_directions_t rec_dir) {rectangle_direction = rec_dir;}


private:
    rectangle_directions_t rectangle_direction;

};

int main()
{
    Rectangle pRect;
    pRect.setRect(R_LEFT);

}
```

Can you not just set a variable of an enum type like any other type? Or am i missing something simple? The error I get is during the "set" in main which says R_LEFT is undefined. Which is odd because I don't usually declare an "int" first if I want to pass it to a method...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The enumeration is defined within your class `Rectangle`. You need to qualify `R_LEFT`:

```
pRect.setRect(Rectangle::R_LEFT);
```